# Independent UITableViewCell heights?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

All of the implementations I've found here require the table view delegate to handle each height. Is there any way each cell can tell the table view delegate what their height is?

I have tried the following implementation with no cigar

Custom UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TETableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //...

    func calculateHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return CGRectGetHeight(labelCaption.frame)
    }

    //...

}
```

Table view delegate class

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TETableViewCell
    return cell.calculateHeight()
}
```

I am aware that this causes an endless cyclic loop. What is the correct way to approach my problem?

Please note that `TETableViewCell` is a base class for all my custom cells so I override `calculateHeight()` for different scenarios.

Comment: Is the height supposed to be dynamic depending on each cell's content?

Comment: Yes. So essentially I create a model for each cell. One could be a text field. Another a radio list. Another a drop down

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why this is getting down voted instead of just down voting it?? I'm really stumped with my query and if there's a simple answer can someone please direct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches on how to achieve what you are trying to do:

**Dynamic cell sizes using Auto Layout**

This would be the best approach as the UITableView would figure out the cell heights by itself without you having to do anything (except layouting the cells with Auto Layout). The downside: this is only available in iOS8 and newer so if you still have to support iOS versions older than iOS8 you cannot use this.

**Using reference/prototype cells to determine cell heights**

This is the old school approach before dynamic cell sizes were available. As you already mentioned it is not possible to ask the actual cells for their height because the `UITableView` needs to know the cell's height before it can draw it on the screen.

What you can do is create reference cells just for height calculation purposes. That cells can have the height calculation method that you have in your example but they have to calculate their heights without being displayed. That sounds a bit strange, but you are probably setting the frames of the cells' subviews anyway, so calculating the cell's height from its subviews frames should be easy. So what you have to do is this:

1. Create a `getHeight(forCellWidth cellWidth: CGFloat, cellData: AnyObject) -> CGFloat` method in each of your cell classes. You need to pass the `width` as a parameter because you have to calculate the cell's height without actually drawing the cell. And for that the cell has to know how wide it would be. You also have to pass the data that should be displayed, so the cell can calculate the height it needs.
2. In your UI(Table)ViewController create a cell for each type and keep a reference to it. These cells will only be used for the height calculation. They won't be displayed and you only need 1 for each class.
3. In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you determine which cell type must be used for that row. Then you call `getHeight::` on the reference cell of that type to get the height. You have to pass the cell width and the cell data to that method.
4. Depending on the complexity of your cell layouts you might want to consider caching the cell heights to only make that calculation once per row and not everytime the user scrolls up and down.

This is only a basic description on how to make it work. Check out this [tutorial](http://www.macspotsblog.com/dynamic-uitableview-cell-heights-programmatically/) which describes this method a bit more detailed. It only uses one cell class but I am sure you can adapt it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I truly appreciate the explanation of the two as I'm still learning the concepts of auto layouts properly and I've always used springs and struts in the past (so method 2 of prototype cells). I am going to look into the proper way for auto layout as it seems much faster.